# How do i write a linq query to get list of records where id in (1,2,3,8,23,45)

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I want to select the list of records for n ids, i have the list of ids and i want to use it at once as we write in sql query select * from abc where id in(3,4,6,7,8,14).
Like this i want to write the linq query.
i wrote something like this:

```
var mylist = (from log in context.mylog
                         where logIdList.Contains(log.Id)
                         select log).ToList();
```

but this is giving me error.

Note: logIdList is the list of Ids.

Comment: What error are you facing?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want something like:

```
var myList = from log in context.mylog
             join id in logIdList on log.Id equals id 
             select log;
```

Answer (score 0):

Check weather this solution works. I have not tried it. So not sure.

```
var MyList = Context.MyLog.Where(x => LogIdList.Contains(x.Id)).ToList();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Does this compile? I think it doesn't

Comment: @GiladGreen it was an error. Could you look at it now?

Comment: I am not sure any of these answers are relevant as I do not know what is the error the OP is getting